# How can I vertically align my single menu background with css in wordpress (verticall-alignment middle not working)

Tags: css, wordpress, button, vertical-alignment

I wanted to create an optical button by adding a backround to a single menu item by css.

I named the items css class in the wordpress menu section menu-button and added the follwing custom css code.

It works as far as i get the background, BUT:

The background is vertically not in the middle, it kind of dropped to the bottom so the text is in line with all  the other menu items but the background hangs down.

I tried adding text-align and vertically-align, not working.

```
  background: #cbbba0;
        padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Comment: i made a screenshot for better understanding of the probelem: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/05f098b68d01b5aece58555cead6317d20190608175241/057805

Comment: do you have any margin-bottom on the <li> elements for your menu buttons